# 'str' object has no attribute 'find_all' beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So this is my code, pretty simple. For some reason, getting the above error. Same error even when I deleted `text = str(html)` and replaced `soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')` with `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`. What's going on?

```
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://jalopnik.com/search?q=mazda&u=&zo=-07:00') as response:
   html = response.read()  
text = str(html)  
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
print(type(soup))
soup = soup.prettify()
print(soup.find_all('div'))
```

Comment: `soup = soup.prettify()` makes `soup` a string. Don't replace your soup with a prettified string.

Answer (score 8):

`soup = soup.prettify()` returns a *string*, and because you assigned it back to `soup`, that makes `soup` a string when you call `soup.find_all()`.

From the [*pretty printing* section of the BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#pretty-printing):

> The `prettify()` method will turn a Beautiful Soup parse tree into a nicely formatted Unicode string.

Don't replace your soup with a prettified string. `BeautifulSoup` doesn't need prettifying, that's only needed when you want to turn the soup back into a  string for saving to a file or debugging.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('div'))
```

works just fine.

You also do *not* want to use `str(html)` to decode the `bytes` object. Normally you'd use `html.decode('utf8')` or similar; `str(html)` gives you a value that starts with `b'` and ends with `'`

However, BeautifulSoup is perfectly capable of decoding bytes values by itself. It can also read directly from the response:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://jalopnik.com/search?q=mazda&u=&zo=-07:00') as response:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('div'))
```